# Is there a Software Development Kit for PHP and MySQL for iPhone?

Tags: php, ios, mysql, iphone

I need to know if there is a development kit for PHP and MySQL on iPhone.

I want to write PHP scripts using my iPhone plus I want to run these scripts on it as a server.

Comment: You can ask over at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ if anyone has any clever ideas, but I suspect the answer is "No", for the same reasons as Apple refuse to provide Flash for iOS.

Comment: @DaveRandom, this will be voted to close as soon as it hits Programmers, IMHO.

Comment: Please don't cross-post the same question to multiple sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure why you would want to, but there are instructions for running PHP using Apache or LightHTTP [here](http://www.hackint0sh.org/f126/7299.htm). They are old, so YMMV.

I don't know of MySQL, but you could try SQLite instead ([Demo from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SQLiteBooks/index.html))?

Answer (score 0):

Search about JQuery Mobile. You can integrate PHP and mysql inside Jquery Mobile to build mobile apps.